# Simplifying cross product expressions

Tags: symbolic, algebra, vector

Suppose I want to calculate:

```
Cross[A1 + B1, A2 - B2] + Cross[A1 - B1, A2 + B2]
```

which is equal to `2 A1xA2 - 2 B1xB2`

Using `FullSimpify` won't do it. I can use `Distribute`

```
Distribute[Cross[A1 + B1, A2 - B2]] + Distribute[Cross[A1 - B1, A2 + B2]]
(* which gives: 2 A1xA2 + A1x(-B2) + A1xB2 + (-B1)xA2 + (-B1)xB2 + B1xA2 + B1x(-B2) *)
```

Close but it still keeps the `-` into parentheses, keeping terms that cancel each other.
How can I overcome this?

Comment: `TensorExpand[Cross[A1+B1,A2-B2]+Cross[A1-B1,A2+B2]]`

Comment: Please post it as an answer. I wasn't aware of `TensorExpand`, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TensorExpand[Cross[A1+B1,A2-B2]+Cross[A1-B1,A2+B2]]`
gives

> 2 A1×A2 - 2 B1×B2