# Simplifying cross product expressions II

Tags: symbolic, syntax, tensors

This is related to [Simplifying cross product expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244413/simplifying-cross-product-expressions/244414#244414)

Consider the following:

```
F2[R + 2 a] = F2[R] + 2 a D[F2[R], R]
F3[R + 3 a] = F3[R] + 3 a D[F3[R], R]
F[R + 4 a] = F[R] + 4 a D[F4[R], R]

FullSimplify[TensorExpand[Cross[F3[R + 3 a], F[R + 4 a] - F2[R + 2 a]]]]

(*=> F[R]\[Cross]F3[R] - 3 F[R]\[Cross](a Derivative[1][F3][R]) + 
 F2[R]\[Cross]F3[R] + 3 F2[R]\[Cross](a Derivative[1][F3][R]) - 
 2 F3[R]\[Cross](a Derivative[1][F2][R]) + 
 4 F3[R]\[Cross](a Derivative[1][F4][R]) + 
 6 (a Derivative[1][F2][R])\[Cross](a Derivative[1][F3][R]) + 
 12 (a Derivative[1][F3][R])\[Cross](a Derivative[1][F4][R])
```

`a` is scalar, but Mathematica doesn't know it, so it isn't moved outside the cross product.

I tried

```
FullSimplify[TensorExpand[Cross[F3[R + 3 a], F[R + 4 a] - F2[R + 2 a]]], 
 Assumptions -> {F[R], F2[R], F3[R], D[F[R], R], D[F3[R], R], D[F2[R], R]} \[Epsilon] Vectors[3]]
```

but the result is the same. How can I specifically declare that `a` is a scalar?

Comment: I don't think it'll necessarily fix it, but note that `\[Epsilon]` is not the same as `\[Element]`!

Comment: Note that `{F[R], F2[R], F3[R], D[F[R], R], D[F3[R], R], D[F2[R], R]} \[Element] Vectors[3]]` does not express what you think it expresses; it says that the single vector `{F[R], F2[R], F3[R], D[F[R], R], D[F3[R], R], D[F2[R], R]}` is in `Vectors[3]` and thus evaluates to `False`. Rather, you need a way of saying they're all in `Vectors[3]`, e.g. `# \[Element] Vectors[3] & /@ {F[R], F2[R], F3[R], D[F[R], R], D[F3[R], R], D[F2[R], R]}`. But for this application, all that's needed is information on `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can give assumptions to `TensorExpand`:

```
TensorExpand[Cross[F3[R + 3 a], F[R + 4 a] - F2[R + 2 a]], 
 Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals}]
```

```
(* Out: 

-F[R]\[Cross]F3[R] - 3 a F[R]\[Cross]Derivative[1][F3][R] + 
 F2[R]\[Cross]F3[R] + 3 a F2[R]\[Cross]Derivative[1][F3][R] - 
 2 a F3[R]\[Cross]Derivative[1][F2][R] + 
 4 a F3[R]\[Cross]Derivative[1][F4][R] + 
 6 a^2 Derivative[1][F2][R]\[Cross]Derivative[1][F3][R] + 
 12 a^2 Derivative[1][F3][R]\[Cross]Derivative[1][F4][R]

*)
```

(You could also use `a \[Element] Complexes` or even `a \[Element Integers`, if you wanted!)

Comment: thanks for the comments and the answer